# Show ToolTip for DataGridView on KeyDown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

So I'm looking for a way to display some help when a key is pressed.  I'm thinking the best option is `ToolTip`.  But how can I get it so it shows instantly on `KeyDown` on a `DataGridView`?  I have the `ToolTip` setup when `KeyDown`is pressed.  However it doesn't show up for some reason.  This is the code in my `KeyDown` event:

```
if (e.Control)
{
    if(tt == null)
    {
        tt = new ToolTip();
        tt.InitialDelay = 0;
        tt.Active = true;
        tt.Show("Help Test", dataGridView1.FindForm());
    }           
}
```

Yet nothing displays when I push down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: You should set `this.dataGridView1.ShowCellToolTips = false;` using designer or using code, then you can show a manual `ToolTip`. 

Also a single instance of `ToolTip` is enough. Drop a `ToolTip` component from toolbox on form and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `this.dataGridView1.ShowCellToolTips = false;` using designer or using code, then you can show a manual `ToolTip`.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Control)
        toolTip1.Show("Some help", this.dataGridView1);
}
```

**Note:** You should dispose a `ToolTip` when the form disposes, so it's better to drop a `ToolTip` component from toolbox on form and use it. This way you don't need to dispose it manually yourself.

Comment: You can set the tooltip to show always. Then you can use `KeyUp` to hide the tooltip.

Comment: Its working now :)  thanks.  I actually had to change it from show to settooltip for the datagridview.  Then on keyup just did a tooltip.removeall() to clear it.

Comment: By the way, as another option, you can use `Help` class and such code: `if(e.Control) Help.ShowPopup(dataGridView1, "Some help", PointToScreen(dataGridView1.Location));` This way by pressing `Control` key it will show a help pop up and then by pressing mouse or any key it hides the help pop up. You may want to take a look at some topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/winforms/3285/help-integration).