# Don't hide Tooltip until remove mouse from the DataGridViewCell in Window Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tooltip

I have to show the tooltip for DataGridViewCell.
Below is the code for this.

```
private void dgrSearch_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && (e.ColumnIndex == this.dgrSearch.Columns["ID"].Index) && e.Value != null)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = this.dgrSearch.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];                
            string tooltip = this.dgrSearch.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Description"].Value.ToString();
            cell.ToolTipText = tooltip;                
        }

    }
```

The default behavior of tooltip in windows is it automatically hide after some time. But my requirement is if the user hovers on the cell then show the tooltip till the mouse is hover on that.

Comment: You can disable the default ToolTip (since you cannot configure it) and provide one yourself. A standard ToolTip with a very high `AutoPopDelay` value, `InitialDelay` and `ReshowDelay` set to `0` and `ShowAlways = true` (as the default ToolTip). In CellEnter, you can set the ToolTip as, e.g.,  `toolTip1.Show("Some Text", dataGridView1, dataGridView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));` and hide it on `CellLeave`.

Comment: This may help: [Show ToolTip for DataGridView on KeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40644683/3110834). Read the comments below the answer.

Comment: You also can find the ToolTip component used by the DataGridView and manipulate it. This may help: [How to refresh tooltip of a DataGridView cell while it's shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496351/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

here is what you are trying to do 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-tooltips-and-infotips?redirectedfrom=MSDN#guidelines

> Appropriate timeouts
>   The appropriate automatic display and removal of tips is crucial to the goal of users maintaining control of their UI environment. Tips have three timeout values:
>
> Initial. The time the pointer must remain stationary for the tip to
>   appear. The default time is 0.5 seconds.
>
> Reshow. The time the pointer must remain stationary as the pointer
>   moves from one target to another. The default time is 0.1 seconds.
>
> Removal. The time after which the tip is automatically removed. The
>   default time is 5 seconds.

Having too short initial and reshow values results in an annoying, disruptive experience because they would often be shown inadvertently, whereas too long results in tips feeling unresponsive or not being discovered. The default removal time works well for short tip text, as used in tooltips. Infotips have longer text, so they need longer display times.